# What's the best way to join multiple unrelated tables in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have multiple unrelated product tables in PostgreSQL that I would like to combine in one extraction. All of them have dates and timestamps, statuses with different values per product, and I would like to get the count of each statuses from each product by hour.

Product 1

| Timestamp | Status | Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-09-11 01:35:38 | Success | 28 |
| 2022-09-11 17:35:02 | Failed | 54 |

Product 2

| Timestamp | Status | Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-09-11 03:45:27 | For Approval | 12 |
| 2022-09-11 12:35:54 | Approved | 82 |

Product 3

| Timestamp | Status | Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-09-11 09:45:23 | Cancelled | 3 |
| 2022-09-11 22:02:43 | For Cancellation | 22 |

Desired Output

| Product | Timestamp | Status | Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Product 1 | 2022-09-11 01:00 | Success | 28 |
| Product 1 | 2022-09-11 17:00 | Failed | 54 |
| Product 2 | 2022-09-11 03:45 | For Approval | 12 |
| Product 2 | 2022-09-11 12:35 | Approved | 82 |
| Product 3 | 2022-09-11 09:45 | Cancelled | 3 |
| Product 3 | 2022-09-11 02:02 | For Cancellation | 22 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `union` or `union all` :

```
select 'Product 1' as product, Timestamp, Status, Count
from Product1
union all
select 'Product 2' as product, Timestamp, Status, Count
from Product2
union all
select 'Product 3' as product, Timestamp, Status, Count
from Product3
```

Comment: `UNION ALL` is the way to go. `UNION` would remove duplicate rows.